# Should I replace the HVAC or install a mini split in my garage?

Tags: hvac, garage, mini-split

I have a detached garage that was built with an HVAC system. Don’t think anything has been updated since the house was built 20 years ago. It was disclosed when I bought the house that it was inoperable. Refrigerant lines are leaking and the condenser would definitely need to be replaced…among other things I’m sure.

If I install a mini split then the ducts become pretty useless but would clear up some space in the attic.

Would I be wasting money to try to fix what I have?

For reference I live in Texas so I’m not typically worried about it getting too cold in there.

Pictures:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuC0o.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVudU.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xYdm.jpg

Comment: Consider a central ducted unit. Mr Cool and others have units that connect to your ducting. [link](https://mrcool.com/central-ducted/). Ducting is a sizable investment that I usually prefer to keep in use. However, the cheapest path is to self-install a minisplit. The best solution depends on your budget, utility rates, home value, how long you plan to keep your property, what you store in your garage and how often you are in your garage (workshop area).

Answer (score 2):

It is fruitless to spend on the 20 yr old HVAC system with the issues you speak of.

I have installed Mini-splits in a few small homes I purchased with problem HVAC systems.  I'm getting ready to do another in the next few weeks.  I have been extremely pleased with the Mini-splits.  I think you will too.

I rent the homes I reno. My info from tenants is that the homes with the minis use less electric. ( sure there are other factors, but the electric usage should be less with the minis.)